# Вывести данные с mysql по порядку

Tags: php, mysql

у меня имеется таблица : `jbe_stats`, в ней есть следующии поля:

```
id
Name
SteamID
player_time (int)
pn_kill_gr
pn_kill_chief
gr_kill_pn
gr_kill_wanted
```

необходимо выводить по порядку дабы в самом верху была запись, где `player_time` больше всех остальных и так по убыванию.

Comment: у вас есть пример кода? что уже пробовали сделать?

Comment: Я использую стандартный код php который нащел в интернете для вывода данных с mysql

Comment: Что необходимо выводить по порядку? Поле player_time больше всех остальных значений относительно чего?

Answer (score 0):

В конце sql запроса укажите, что сортируете по полю jbe_stats:

```
SELECT ... ORDER BY jbe_stats DESC;
```

Comment: Правда по player_time сортировка. jbe_stats - это таблица